# Google Calendar API in JS

Tags: javascript, api

*Hope Everybody is good in this covid pandemic.*

I am working on google calendar api using js. I was trying to fetch events from my calendar using API-Key only.

```
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        },
        
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'myCalendar'sAPIkey',
        
        eventClick: function (arg) {
          window.open(arg.event.url, 'google-calendar-event', 'width=700,height=600');

          arg.jsEvent.preventDefault() // don't navigate in main tab
        },

        initialDate: '2020-09-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        businessHours: true, // display business hours
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
*~*        // events: 'en.pk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
*~*        events: [
          {
            title: 'Business Lunch',
            start: '2020-09-03T13:00:00',
            constraint: 'businessHours'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2020-09-13T11:00:00',
            constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
            color: '#257e4a'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2020-09-18',
            end: '2020-09-20'
          },
          {
            title: 'Party',
            start: '2020-09-29T20:00:00'
          },

          // areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
          {
            groupId: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2020-09-11T10:00:00',
            end: '2020-09-11T16:00:00',
            display: 'background'
          },
          {
            groupId: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2020-09-13T10:00:00',
            end: '2020-09-13T16:00:00',
            display: 'background'
          },

          // red areas where no events can be dropped
          {
            start: '2020-09-24',
            end: '2020-09-28',
            overlap: false,
            display: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
          },
          {
            start: '2020-09-06',
            end: '2020-09-08',
            overlap: false,
            display: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
          }
        ]
      
      });

      calendar.render();
```

> *~*
> if I use **events: 'en.pk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',** and comments **events**
> below it, I get all the holidays
> similarly if I comment **events: 'en.pk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'** and use **events** >it show custom defined events. but how can I get both.

*OS: windows 10,
Editor: VS code,*